# handle pagination recursively

Tags: python, django, python-requests

I'm using `requests` lib to fetch data from remote server and I'm saving the data in the model, but I need to handle pagination, currently I'm only loading one page from server.

I have a url for pagination like so

```
{
"status": "success",
"count": 32,
"total": 32,
"next": "https://pimber.ly/api/v2/products?sinceId=5c3ca8470985af0016229b5b",
"previous": "https://pimber.ly/api/v2/products?maxId=5c3ca8470985af0016229b04",
"sinceId": "5c3ca8470985af0016229b04",
"maxId": "5c3ca8470985af0016229b5b",
"data": [
    {
        "Primary ID": "API_DOCS_PROD1",
        "Product Name": "Example Product 1",
        "Product Reference": "Example Reference 1",
        "Buyer": "Example Buyer 1",
        "_id": "5c3ca8470985af0016229b04",
        "primaryId": "API_DOCS_PROD1"
    },
```

I've tried to use python generator to handle current situation but, that does not do anything

```
_plimber_data = response.json()
yield _plimber_data
_next = _plimber_data['next']
print(_next)
for page in _next:
    _next_page = session.get(_plimber_data, params={'next': page}).json()
    yield _next_page['next']

    for _data in page:
        Product.objects.create(
            qr_id=_data['primaryId'],
            ean_code=_data['EAN'],
            description=_data['Description105'],
            category=_data['Category'],
            marketing_text=_data['Marketing Text'],
            bullet=_data['Bullet 1'],
            brand_image=_data['Brand Image'],
            image=_data['Images']
        )
        logger.debug(f'Something went wrong {_data}')
        print(f'This is the Data:{_data}')
```

Can someone please explain me how to handle this so I can load all the data into the database, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I've solved it, two thinks first generator function

```
def _get_product():
    """
    TODO: Fetch data from server
    """
    headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': settings.TOKEN
    }

    try:
        response = requests.get(
            url=f'{settings.API_DOMAIN}',
            headers=headers
        )
        response.raise_for_status()
    except HTTPError as http_err:
        print(f'HTTP error occurred: {http_err}')

    else:
        _plimber_data = response.json()
        while _plimber_data['next'] is not None:
            response = requests.get(
                _plimber_data['next'],
                headers=headers
            )
            _plimber_data = response.json()
            for _data in _plimber_data['data']:
                yield _data
```

Then I iterate over generator function, and save the data:

```
    def run(self):
    _page_data = _get_product()
    for _product in _page_data:
        Product.objects.create(
            qr_id=_product['primaryId'],
            ean_code=_product['EAN'],
            description=_product['Description105'],
            category=_product['Category'],
            marketing_text=_product['Marketing Text'],
            bullet=_product['Bullet 1'],
            brand_image='\n'.join(_product['Brand Image']),
            image='\n'.join(_product['Images'])
        )
        logger.debug(f'Something went wrong {_product}')
        print(f'This is the Data:{_product}')
```

Comment: Note, I would not call this a recursive solution, as you don't call _get_product() from within its own function definition.

Comment: @StuartJCuthbertson you are right will try to fix the answer, nevertheless, it works for me

Comment: I think this is a perfectly fine way to implement API results pagination, and indeed, for large results sets, possibly much wiser than a true recursive solution. Not knocking your code itself, just commenting as the question specifies a recursive solution. Perhaps changing the question title (if possible) to match the answer, would be the best thing here? I don't think you actually cared about a recursive implementation specifically?